# Require Email When Creating an Account with Django

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I've got a Django project, which requires users to be able create accounts to access content.

I'm using the `UserCreationForm` to do this.

In `views.py` I have

```
def register_user(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data["password1"])
            new_user.save()
            template = "account/registration/registration_done.html"
            context = {"new_user": new_user}
        else:
            # TODO: Handle exception
            raise BaseException
    elif request.method == "GET":
        user_form = UserCreationForm()
        template = "account/registration/register.html"
        context = {"user_form": user_form}
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError

    return render(request, template, context=context)
```

And then my template is:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Create an Account{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Create an Account</h1>
    <form action="." method="post">
        {{ user_form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Create my account"></p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Which works okay. But when the create account form is displayed, it only has fields for the username, password, and password verification. There's no requirement that the user enter a valid email.

What I'd like to do is have a have the user be required to enter an email address, and then send them an email to ensure that the address is valid, and that they have access to is etc.

Surely this is a common enough pattern that there's already a way to implement is using Django's authentication? Or will I need to write all the forms and handling etc myself?

Answer (score 0):

Override the Meta class of the UserCreationForm

In your forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class YourUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm)
     class Meta:
         fields = ("username", "email")
```

and use YourUserCreationForm instead

Comment: That exposes the email field, but won't send a verification email.

Comment: use the post_save signal on the user model, check for the 'created' keyword argument, if True, then send an email